# Cordova app crashes after I touch the screen with targetSdk 30

Tags: java, android, cordova, crash, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova-android@10.0.0 to build the app. Though the app gets built successfully and also gets installed on the device. But after a touch on the screen the app crashes with the following error

Logcat:

```
11-30 19:18:37.150 19894 19894 E InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
11-30 19:18:37.150 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.isShown()' on a null object reference
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at nl.xservices.plugins.Toast$1$1.onTouch(Toast.java:149)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14504)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3180)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2817)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3186)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2774)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3186)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2774)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3186)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2774)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3186)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2774)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3186)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2774)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:571)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1889)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4211)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:521)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14776)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6749)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6515)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6004)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5963)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6149)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5971)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6206)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5944)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6004)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5963)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5971)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5944)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8947)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8898)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8849)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9093)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8282)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
11-30 19:18:37.151 19894 19894 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

Gradle version used: 6.7.1

Plugins used:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.7.0",
    "angular-loading-bar": "^0.9.0",
    "asyncawait": "^1.0.8",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-ourcodeworld-filebrowser": "git+https://github.com/ourcodeworld/cordova-ourcodeworld-filebrowser.git",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-event": "1.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "git+https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "1.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-email": "1.2.7",
    "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "1.5.8",
    "cordova-plugin-filepickerio": "0.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "10.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus.git",
    "cordova-plugin-image-picker": "1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-market": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-sim": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "2.7.2",
    "cordova-plugins-reinstall": "0.0.1",
    "cordova-sqlcipher-adapter": "0.5.1",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "1.4.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "6.0.2",
    "es6-set": "^0.1.5",
    "fabric": "^3.6.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.9",
    "ionic-tooltips": "^2.0.1",
    "mailcheck": "^1.1.1",
    "marked": "^1.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "secure-ls": "^1.2.5",
    "snyk": "^1.280.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

Also, no luck with changing the Gradle version to 7.1.1.
Any Solution?

Comment: The error is due to toast plugin. Here you can check the updates - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/141

Comment: @AkshayaJeevan No luck with upgrading that plugin too.

Comment: Had the same issue, solution was to upgrade plugin cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2-> 2.7.3